# URL rotator in specific order

Tags: php, url, rotator

I want to create an URL rotator script that will rotate my URLs in a specific order,not randomly.

let say I have 100 URLS to rotate, I have them ordered and the rotator will show them from the first one until the last one, then return to the first URL and so on.

if possible can it be a simple php script with no database?

Comment: Do you want to show the sequence of links to each individual user, or show the sequence to ALL the users?  In other words, if I visit this page, should I see all the individual links in sequence, or should your entire audience as a group see the links in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
define('FILEDB', 'count.db');
define('URLDB', 'url.db');

function readURLS()
{
  $fp = fopen(URLDB, 'r');

  if( null == $fp )
    return false;

  $retval = array();
  while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false)
  {
    $retval[] = $line;
  }

  return $retval;
}

$list = readURLS();

if( false === $list )
{
  echo "No URLs available";
}
else
{
  $fp = fopen(FILEDB, 'a+');

  $count = (fread($fp, filesize(FILEDB)) + 1) % count($list);

  ftruncate($fp, 0);
  fwrite($fp, "{$count}");
  fclose($fp);

  echo $list[$count];
}
```

this works.

---

updated with new requirements.
You'll need a file named url.db (or whatever you fill in after the `define('URLDB', 'xxx')`
Each line is an URL entry.

count.db can exist, but doesn't need to. It is better to create one with a simple `0` in it.

It will rotate through all URL entries in the `url.db` file on each 'request'.

However this is not concurrent safe. If person A requests the page and person B does as well there might be a chance that A and B see the same URL if B reads `count.db` before A has written the new contents to `count.db`

Comment: Can you please post all the steps needed to create this script? I'm not php guru :(

Comment: I tested that, but it doesn't show the URL in iframe or redirect to it! it just show the URL as a text !

Comment: Ok guys, just fixed the problem, and I think this is what I need :) .

@Daan Timmer : Thanks a lot.

Comment: in order for this code to work, you have to add the URLs in url.db as iframe , one iframe in each line, and when the rotator page loads , it will show the iframe you entered in url.db .

Answer (score 3):

It could be done without a database, yes.  You could create a simple script with an arbitrary array of URLs and a text file with a number in it.  The number tracks the index of the array for the URL to display.  When the script is loaded, read the file, get the number, and display the associated URL.  Then increment the number and write it back to the file unless the number now exceeds the size of the array - then write a zero back to the file.

To accomplish this with the URLS in a file (and no counter), put all the URLs on a single line of text.  Separate them with the `|` pipe character. On the following line, put a zero.  Read in the first line and explode on the pipe character to make an array.  Get the first element from the array, use that URL, and move the first array element to the end of the array.  Implode the array with the pipe character back to a string and overwrite the file contents to the text file.

Depending on your plan, this will or won't work with cookies.  Since cookies are stored in the client browser, you can only track what the individual visitor has seen.  If the entire audience needs to be considered, this will not help because you'd need a group array index to track, not an individual one.

Comment: and how file is not database it stores data no? :D

Comment: Can you please post the full code of this php page?

Comment: @Vytautas If you want to go that way, you could even call the php file itself a *database*. A simple text-file instead of a rdms is probably what the op is looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I want the list of URLS in .txt file, and the rotator in .php file, maybe use cookies to memorise the order?!

Comment: maybe, it's hard to guess what he wants..

Comment: I think it's clear what I want, 2 files:
txt or php file with a list of URLs in specific order.
php file to rotate those URLs in the order I chose in the first file.

Comment: In fairness, a text file with a number in it could be considered a flat text database.  So could a file with all the URLS in it.

Comment: @SurrealDreams True, but in this context, I don't really think it's a distinction the op would make. ;)

Comment: yeah, but I don't want it with database, just using files

Comment: @user, the idea of URL in one file and script in another wasn't clear.  How it works for the audience isn't clear either - see my question on your original post.

Comment: @SurrealDreams , dono witch is better, but if you have a working solution for my issue please post it here.   I just want to rotate some URLs in a specific order using php with no database even if they can be all in one file